# Why can't I stretch a window across multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, window, aero

I am running

- Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 with no third-party window managers or monitor support.
- Not remoted in via Citrix or `rdp`
- 4 1280x1024 monitors horizontally with *Extend destop to this display* set for all of them

Recently I've lost the ability to span *some* (not all) windows across monitors. As soon as the window crosses into another monitor, the window snaps back. If I go more than 50% across the next monitor, the window snaps to that monitor.

- This happens either when resizing or when moving.
- This happens whether aero shake is off or on.
- This happens when *Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen* in **Ease of Access Center** is off or on.
- Changing themes doesn't help (including switching to Windows 7 Basic).
- Killing `dwm` didn't help.
- Killing `explorer` and/or rebooting didn't help.

Windows that will span:

- Task Manager
- Regedit
- cmd
- Powershell

Example of some that won't:

- Explorer
- Visual Studio
- Outlook 2013

I don't have this issue on any other Windows 7 or 10 machine I have, so clearly there is some setting or registry entry somewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is restoring the machine with your companies standard image a possibility? Is the hardware identical to the other machines?

Comment: Try updating your video drivers or maybe rolling them back, checking windows optional updates for monitors.